# Function stops executing once the player wins

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a simple game based on which player clicks the button to 100% faster. Each of the players have a button allocated for them and depending on who clicks faster the player wins. I want to make a logic where if the COUNT or COUNT_PLAYER2 exceed 100 the player one or two wins and all the functions stop executing. Can you please help me with the logic behind that?

```
let count = 0;
let maxCount = 50;
let player1_progress = document.getElementsByClassName("player1-progress__progressbar")[0];
console.log(player1_progress);
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  //if the button is "d"
  if (e.keyCode === 100) {
    console.log(count)
    // increase count if it's less than 100
    count = count === 100 ? 100 : count + 4;
    //target progressbar width and increase it
    let newWidth = (count / maxCount) * 50 + "%";
    player1_progress.style.width = newWidth;
    player1_progress.innerHTML = count + "%";
    if (count === 100) {
      console.log("player 1 is the winner!");
    }
  }
});

//player2 count

let count_player2 = 0;
let player2_progress = document.getElementsByClassName("player2-progress__progressbar")[0];
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  //if the button is "d"
  if (e.keyCode === 47) {
    // increase count if it's less than 100
    count_player2 = count_player2 === 100 ? 100 : count_player2 + 4;
    //target progressbar width and increase it
    let newWidth_player2 = (count_player2 / maxCount) * 50 + "%";
    player2_progress.style.width = newWidth_player2;
    player2_progress.innerHTML = count + "%";
    if (count_player2 === 100) {
      console.log("player 2 is the winner!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Add the complete current execution inside an `if` block with the necessary checks?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried remove all event listeners when one of counts reaches 100?

something like this:

```
button_a_handler = e => {
// do stuff

if (count >= 100) {
  window.removeEventListener("keypress", button_a_handler);
  window.removeEventListener("keypress", button_b_handler);
}
};

 button_b_handler = e => {
 // do stuff

 if (count >= 100) {
   window.removeEventListener("keypress", button_a_handler);
   window.removeEventListener("keypress", button_b_handler);
 }
};
```